# Packagemaker postfligh script

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I have created an installer using packagemaker, but i don't see how to add a postfligh script with the PackageMaker UI.

I try the to put a "postflight.sh" in resources folder, and pass the --resources command line option when build the package but that seems to not work.

packagemaker --doc myinstaller.pmdoc --resources resources --out mypackage.pkg

But the postflight.sh script doesn't seems to run, the script is executable and works fine from console, any ideas?

I using latest Xcode 4.2 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but if I understand it right you need to name the script "postinstall" (no .sh extension), and pass the directory it's in with `--scripts path/to/scripts/directory` instead of `--resources`.

Comment: postinstall ins't the same as postflight, see http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html, using --script doesn't run the postflight, if you look at the installer layout show in the link, postfligh script should be in the Resources folder, but this doesn't seem to work with my installer that use the pmdoc.

Comment: What minimum OS X version are you targeting? If it's 10.5, you're building a flat package, which only has 2 scripts: preinstall and postinstall, which function like preflight and postflight did in the old bundle-based packages (i.e. they always run, whether it's a new install or an upgrade).

Comment: Thanks fo clarifications, i target 10.5 as minimum, so seems i need to use the postinstall.